# Capture result of Question and store together with Hostname

Tags: powershell, string-concatenation

wonder if someone can help me. Im trying to run a script that prompts a question box, stores the question on a variable together with the computer name and outputs both variables to a file

i did managed to get this function but dont have enough knowledge on how to add and concatenate an hostname string to output also the computer name

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationCore,PresentationFramework

$msgBody = "Your computer will restart soon 

Do you want to restart now ?"

$msgTitle = "Confirm Reboot"
$msgButton = 'YesNoCancel'
$msgImage = 'Question'
$Result = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)
$result | Out-file \\share\xxxxx
```

Comment: where is the computer name you want to concatenate? thinking you're asking for `'{0}: {1}' -f $env:COMPUTERNAME, $Result | Out-File...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not combine both properties in an **object** and save that as CSV or Json file?

Something like

```
$msgBody = "Your computer will restart soon`r`n`r`nDo you want to restart now ?"

$msgTitle  = "Confirm Reboot"
$msgButton = 'YesNoCancel'
$msgImage  = 'Question'
$answer = [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($msgBody,$msgTitle,$msgButton,$msgImage)
$result = '' | Select-Object @{Name = 'ComputerName'; Expression = {$env:COMPUTERNAME}},
                             @{Name = 'RebootConfirmed'; Expression = {$answer}}

$result | Export-Csv -Path '\\share\xxxxx.csv' -NoTypeInformation
# or as json
# $result | ConvertTo-Json | Set-Content -Path '\\share\xxxxx.json'
```

Comment: Thanks Theo, but for some reason when running the script the hostname is not being captured outputs as:     ComputerName RebootConfirmed
                                      ------------ ---------------
                                           No                        No

Comment: Thanks Theo , replacing {$env:COMPUTERNAME}} by hostname sorts the problem. Thanks for your help

Comment: @user21486214 Thanks for the feedback. If you feel my answer solved your problem, please mark this post 'done'. You can see how that works in the 2-minute read called the [tour]